# API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG error for Salesforce enterprise Trial

Tags: rest-api, enterprise

I was trying access REST API from an **enterprise trial** Salesforce account and I am getting error with error code API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG. I have administrator profile in Salesforce and tried looking for API ENABLED permission under profiles, but I could not find one.

Any one has any idea why enterprise edition doesn't have API permission. Generally they say that enterprise gets the API permission by default.

Below is the screen shot of admin permissions
[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing a screenshot of the "Administrative Permissions" section of the admin profile?

Comment: Thanks @martin for the reply .. i have attached the screen shot in the post

Comment: Are you sure that's not professional edition…

Comment: oh yea .. you are correct .. that was a professional edition .i did register using the below link which says enterprise trial .. https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales-ee.jsp .. anyhow thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

None of the trial orgs have API accessible for them.

Comment: Abhijeet -- please refer to [community etiquette](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/what-sfse-etiquette-should-be-followed) over soliciting upvotes/solutions

Comment: @Abhijeet thanks for the reply, can you please point me to the page where it is mentioned that trial orgs doesnot have API Permission. Surprising thing is, i am able to make calls with SOAP but not REST

Comment: @karuna i would request you to send me a snapshot of your org which shows its an enterpise trial org if possible

Comment: @Abhijeet its a mistake from my side .. actually it was a professional edition ..i did register using the below link which says enterprise trial .. salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales-ee.jsp .. but somehow it gave professional .. thanks for your help